# How can I define callback function as parameter

Tags: swift, function, callback, alamofire

I want to create a global HTTP request function/extension with Alamofire. It's like:

```
function Request(requestPath:String, requestParams:Any, onComplate:Void) {
 // stuff here, when async request complate i want to call onComplate function
 // like C# method.Invoke() or func.Invoke()
}
```

Comment: you can use Clousers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for reply but finally solution

```
class HttpRequest<Request, Response>
{
    private var serviceBase:String = "http://192.168.1.1/api";
    func request(path:String, model: Request, success: @escaping((_ response: [Response]?) -> ()), failure: @escaping ((_ error:String) -> ()) {
         // code here..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just pass the closure(function) as parameter

```
swift
func request(requestPath:String, requestParams:Any, callback:((Result) -> Void)) { 
    ... 
}
```

Where `Result` will be the type of your response.

Comment: Thanks for reply check my solution :)